# Как заставить отрендерить заново родительский компонент из дочернего в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Предположим, есть дерево список>элемент списка->форма->кнопка сабмит. Мне нужно отрендерить дерево заново при нажатии на сабмит, как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если каждый из описанных вами элементов представляет отдельный компонент, то вы можете передать из компонента верхнего уровня функцию, меняющую его state. Эта техника называется подъём состояния, подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: Я видимо не могу понять. Я должен передать из списка в элемент, из элемента в форму State самого списка? Затем мне придет это состояние в this.props в форму, как мне изменить его потом?

Comment: @Enkei нет, нужно передавать функцию, объявленную в компоненте родителя (списка в вашем случае) и меняющую его state, через props-ы, после чего вызывать её в нужном дочернем компоненте

Comment: @Enkei в родительском компоненте вы можете определить функцию onClick = () => this.setState({ toggle: true }); Затем передайте её дочерним компонентам через пропсы и вызывайте в нужный момент.

Comment: @smolin-pavel Окей, я сделал это, все работает. Теперь вопрос в другом: я делаю запрос на сервер в componentDidMount в компоненте списка, он изменяет state несколько раз. Когда я изменяю this.state.toggle, componentDidMount не выполняется повторно и не получает новые данные с сервера. В какой метод мне нужно перенести запрос на сервер, чтобы он выполнялся при каждом обновлении state?

Comment: @Enkei все верно, componentDidMount отрабатывает только один раз. Можно использовать componentDidMount (для первого рендера) и componentDidUpdate (для последующих обновлений). Подробнее - тут https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate